# Sympy absolute value of complex exponential

Tags: python, sympy, simplification

When working with complex numbers in polar form, I've experienced a strange behavior. For example, doing

```
from sympy import *
simplify(Abs(exp(I)))
```

I would expect the result 1 because the absolute value of a complex exponential should always be one if the exponent is only imaginary. However, sympy gives as answer

```
Abs(exp(I))
```

Doing the alternative

```
phi=symbols('phi', real=True)
y=exp(I*phi)
sqrt(y*conj(y))
```

gives the expected result but is less clear than abs in my opinion. Did I miss some constraint that prevents sympy from performing this simplification when just using abs?

Comment: simplify isn't meant to perform the calculations, I guess?

Comment: Well, for what reason? It does also not really matter if the simplify is there or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`simplify` could definitely be smarter about this.

In general, to simplify things using complex numbers, use `expand_complex`, which tries to rewrite the expression as `a + b*I`, where `a`, and `b` are real.  This works for me.

```
In [17]: (abs(exp(I))).expand(complex=True)
Out[17]:
   ___________________
  ╱    2         2
╲╱  cos (1) + sin (1)

In [18]: simplify(abs(exp(I)).expand(complex=True))
Out[18]: 1
```